# How can I read a checkbox state in blueprism i.e., whether it is checked or unchecked?

Tags: checkbox, blueprism

I have 3 check boxes in my process and two of those need to be checked while the third checkbox needs to be unchecked. I am working with a browser based application and these check boxes are modeled as active accessibility elements in the application modeler. When I run my process there are cases(1 out of 5 times) when the process skips checking one of the check boxes and I would like to be able to read the checkbox to know whether they are in a checked or unchecked state so that my process throws an error and does not proceed further.

What I tried:

I tried adding a wait stage after the checkbox action in which I included the element but the only conditions I can see are "check exists" , "check window attribute" and "check AA attribute".

Answer (score 0):

Use Read State, Use "Is Connected" Option. you will get the result as a flag, 
keep a decision box, and go future

Comment: the read state with "is connected" option is only for the application window I think. When I use an element, in this case the check box the actions for it that I see in the read state are "get value" "get attribute" etc

Answer (score 0):

Use Read Box, "Get value" property.

It should return "true" or "false".

Comment: When I modelled my checkbox it was stored as a AA element with datatype Text. So when I add the readbox with the get value property the data type is still text and not flag. So I wont be able to get the true or false value.

Comment: I am sorry I meant the data type for the "get value" property is text so irrespective of the fact that the modelled element is of flag or text data type when I add the read stage, the get value property is set to text because of which the output will be in that form. Please correct me if I am wrong and I would appreciate an alternative solution.

Comment: The value of it should be "True" or "False". If you'll try to put it into data item of "flag" type, then it should be correctly cast to that data type.